# Regex if contains X select Y else select Z

Tags: php, regex

At the moment I have got:

```
/(?=(site\.com))site\.com\/u\/(^[\s]+)|\/u\/([^\s]+)/
```

but its not working how expected, I want to test if the string has `site.com` before "/u/", if it has then make sure thats before the selector else just select after "/u/".

The expected result:

```
/u/user thhh                   -> return user

site.com/u/user dsfdsfds       -> return user

site2.com/u/user sdfdsfds      -> return null
```

Comment: please use another delimiter

Comment: This is unclear: "I want to test if the string has the site.com before it if it has, do select via the first regex else select from the last regex."

Comment: Your caret is outside of the character class.

Comment: Oh. The or-pipe `|` was hiding in there. Didn't catch it.

Comment: How's the `thhh`, `dsfdsfds`, `sdfdsfds` fit in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
~site\.com/u/(\S+)|(?<!\S)/u/(\S+)~
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kJ7hA3/1)

Alternatively, you can do this without capturing groups as well. The `\K` escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included.

```
~site\.com/u/\K\S+|(?<!\S)/u/\K\S+~
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kJ7hA3/2)

Comment: What's the tilde for?

Comment: @Eric: Ah. I don't use PHP. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Without any capturing groups,

```
(?<=site\.com\/u\/)\S+|(?<=^\/u\/)\S+
```

OR

```
site\.com\/u\/\K\S+|^\/u\/\K\S+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zN6mX8/2)

Answer (score 0):

I would first sort the input with logic, and only use regex after the input is analyzed.

```
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;    

public class PostSlashUSlash  {    

   private static final String SPECIAL_SITE = "site.com";
   private static final String SLASH_U_REGEX_POST = "/u/(\\w+).*$";
   private static final Matcher mtchrPostU = Pattern.compile(
      "^" + SLASH_U_REGEX_POST).matcher("");
   private static final Matcher mtchrWSpecialSite = Pattern.compile(
      "^" + SPECIAL_SITE + SLASH_U_REGEX_POST).matcher("");  

   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      System.out.println(getImportantPart("/u/user thhh"));            
      System.out.println(getImportantPart(SPECIAL_SITE + "/u/user dsfdsfds")); 
      System.out.println(getImportantPart("site2.com/u/user sdfdsfds"));  
   }
   private static final String getImportantPart(String url)  {
      if(url.charAt(0) == '/')  {
         return  mtchrPostU.reset(url).replaceAll("$1");
      }  else if(mtchrWSpecialSite.reset(url).matches())  {
         return  mtchrWSpecialSite.replaceAll("$1");
      }
      return  null;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
user
user
null
```

(I don't know PHP, so forgive the different language.)

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already accepted an answer, but for completion here's a shorter option, assuming you are testing the strings one by one (as opposed to looking for them in the middle of other text):

```
^(?:site\.com)?/u/\K\S+
```

In php:

```
$theregex = '~^(?:site\.com)?/u/\K\S+~';
if (preg_match($theregex, $yourstring)) {
    // Yes! It matches!
    } 
else { // nah, no luck...
     }
```